# Python list of possible combinations

Tags: python

I am new to Python but need to solve specific topic
lets say I have a totalOfItems = 133 and I have a plates which accomodate [5,25,30] list of items....

How can I find each possible combination so all of the items can be addressed [133]

So it can be like 4x25 + 30 + 5 or 4x30 + 5 or 4x30 + 25 etc...

I've tried to solve it using coin problem but this is not working:

```
#find combination
def findCombination(combinations, arr, temp, sum, index):
    
    if(sum == 0):
        
        # Adding deep copy of list to ans
        combinations.append(list(temp))
        return
    
    # Iterate from index to len(arr) - 1
    for i in range(index, len(arr)):

        # checking that sum does not become negative
        if(sum - arr[i].numParcelsWillFit) >= 0:

            # adding element which can contribute to
            # sum
            temp.append(arr[i])
            findCombination(combinations, arr, temp, sum-arr[i].numParcelsWillFit, i)

            # removing element from list (backtracking)
            temp.remove(arr[i])
```

Comment: 4x30+25 is listed as what you so it could be, but that adds to 120+25=145, which is greater than 133, yea?

Comment: You need an exact equality ? Or could the sum be greater than `totalOfItems` ?